# Rsync backups: checksums don’t match

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, checksum

I am a little confused by this although

```
diff –rq  dir/ dir1/
```

does not show a difference 
This rsync is to backup the directory

```
rsync -avrREz --delete --links -e "ssh -l user" --delete dir/ site.net:dir/ && tar -c /dir/ | md5sum
```

but it does not seems to give me the same checksums when I do a tar on the destination directory

```
tar –c dir/ | md5sum
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's all sorts of metadata that goes into a tarball that can cause md5sum not to match.  I've written this sort of verification script before, and I recall having to stuff around a bit to get rid of all the things that cause verification failures.

Comment: For instance, it includes the file paths. So `tar -c dir` and `tar -c dir1` will *always* have different output.